# The first derivative of inverse hyperbolic sin

Tags: derivatives, hyperbolic-functions, inverse-function

If I know $ sinh^{-1}(x) $  = $ ln(x+ (1 + x^{2} ) ^ { \frac{1}{2} } )  $

I know a way to evaluate that derivative, it is : $\frac {1}{(1 + x^{2} )^{\frac{1}{2}} }$ but is it acceptable to take $ \frac{d}{dx} $ both sides above and work it out?

I have attempted it anyhow on RHS and here are the steps so far :

$ \frac{d}{dx}  ln(x+ (1 + x^{2} ) ^ { \frac{1}{2} } ) = \frac { f'(x) } { f(x) } 
 [ $ where $ f (x) = (x+ (1 + x^{2} ) ^ { \frac{1}{2} } ) $ ]
$ = \frac { 1+ \frac{(x^{2} +1)^{\frac{-3}{2}}}{2} }{x+ (x^{2}+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}} $

and this is where I stopped.

Edit :

the reason was a simple mistake in differentation in the last step where it should be $ \frac {-1}{2} $ instead of $ \frac {-3}{2} $ which lead to problems with the simplification. Mark's answer is complete.

Comment: shouldn't it be -1/2 for the exponent on top

Comment: no it's just a normal square root.. here's how http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/metric/metric_public/functions_and_graphs/hyperbolic_functions/inverses.html

Comment: I hope you know the much simpler way of getting the derivative, i.e. implicit differentiation.

Comment: @Deepak , i think i have an intuition on it since it's how the implicit function is defined ( i guess ) but i haven't tried to drive with it. i will try and update .

Comment: If you've ever seen the derivation using implicit derivatives for the inverse trig functions, the development is basically identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the following:

$$f(x)=sinh^{-1}(x)=log(x+(x^2+1)^{1/2})$$

So, taking the derivative of both sides yields:

$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {1+\frac {x}{(x^2+1)^{1/2}}}{x+(1+x^2)^{1/2}}$$

This is simply via the chain rule, noting $\frac {d}{dx}log(x)=\frac 1x$, so $\frac {d}{dx}log(g(x))=\frac {g'(x)}{g(x)}$

So, combine the two fractions in the numerator into a single fraction:

$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {(x^2+1)^{1/2}+x}{(x^2+1)^{1/2}}\cdot \frac {1}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}+x}=\frac {1}{(x^2+1)^{1/2}}$$